# Can't connect to Tor-Firefox via Watir

Tags: firefox, selenium, watir, watir-webdriver, tor

I am having issues connecting to Tor via Ruby - Watir webdriver.

I use the Tor Browser Bundle. The problem is that when I try to connect via Watir (Selenium) I cannot seem to open Tor instead of regular Firefox.

Looking at similar issues I've tried the following:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new

profile['network.proxy.socks'] = '127.0.0.1' #the proxy tor uses
profile['network.proxy.socks_port'] = 9150 #I cannot use 9050, 9150 works when I use Tor
profile['network.proxy.type'] = 1

browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile
browser.goto [an .onion website]
```

When I use the before-mentioned code I nonetheless still open the normal firefox browser, and cannot connect to onion sites.

Any thoughts? Is there another way in which I need to connect the Tor browser to my webdriver profile?

Comment: I believe the problem is that you have to explicitly tell WebDriver which browser binary to use. Try something iike this: Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = '/path/to/tor/browser/bin'

Comment: You might also need to add WebDriver extension to browser somehow.

Comment: Thanks @p0deje - but what do you mean exactly, to change the binary path? For example: 
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='/path/to/tor/browser/bin'  ?

Comment: Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='/path/to/tor/start-browser-bundle' seems to work! All the profile stuff I have above is no longer necessary

Comment: Please, add the answer then so other people could find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer:

First, open the Tor browser (it needs to be running already).
Then, in your code, make sure to simply start with:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='{location of start_tor_browser*}'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
```

*In my case: 
/home/tor/tor-browser_en-US/start-tor-browser

Nothing else is required - don't bother messing with profile

Comment: Ok, it's this answer is old, but maybe somebody takes a look here. I just can't understand, how it's possible to Tor browser already to be running if when I go with code from answer than I have error - 'Tor Browser is already running, but is not responding. To open a new window, you must first close the existing Tor Browser process, or restart your system.' What I do wrong?

Comment: I used same things, tor browser also opened but in console it stop the process to run next line, after few min it show Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError Exception: connection refused and the browser variable assign with nil
How can I use browser.goto "example.com"