# Watir with Tor browser

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver, tor

I've been playing with Watir and Tor browser and I can't get them to work.
The correct browser opens, however, I'm unable to open a website.

My code:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = '\path\Tor Browser\Start Tor Browser.exe'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :driver => driver
```

This results in a message box popping up, which says:

> Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible.

The correct browser also opens up, however, the website doesn't.

I've also tried:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox.path = '\path\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe'
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :driver => driver
```

With this, the message box doesn't appear, but still, the website is not loaded.

I'm not sure, if the problem is in my code or in the browser.
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Your way is wrong... Why are you using `Firefox` class, to open another browser ?

Comment: Because, as far as I know, Tor browser is pretty much Firefox that just goes through the Tor network

Comment: There was a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305345/cant-connect-to-tor-firefox-via-watir). Perhaps the answer there will help you?

Comment: It should help:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305345/cant-connect-to-tor-firefox-via-watir

Answer (score 3):

Start Tor then run this, assuming your socks port is 9050

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['network.proxy.socks'] = "127.0.0.1"
profile['network.proxy.socks_port'] = 9050
profile['network.proxy.type'] = 1
$browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, :profile => profile

$browser.goto "whatsmyip.org"
```

Answer (score 0):

Firefox and Tor are not the same browser. Watir uses webdriver API to control the browser. You can't use Firefox webdriver API to control another browser.

In your second example, browser don't open the site, but you don't tell him to. You should add :

```
browser.goto('http://my.example.com')
```

And don't forget to put a `browser.quit` at the end of your code to close the browser.