# Tor browser with Watir doesn't respond to commands

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, tor

I've open my Tor browser (6.0.5), but it doesn't respond to Watir browser commands (`goto, click`) and after while gives me the error `Net::ReadTimeout`. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305345/cant-connect-to-tor-firefox-via-watir/24649834#24649834) I found that Tor should be already opened, but if I do so Tor gives me the error "Already opened".

my code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'

Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Binary.path='/.../start-tor-browser'
browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox
sleep 20000
#browser.link(:id =>"testTorSettings").when_present.click
browser.goto('http://google.com')
```

How to use Watir with Tor?